# Pattern-matching on Rationals in Haskell

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, rational-number, rational-numbers

The following function is pretty straightforward:

```
test :: Int -> Int
test x = case x of
    0 -> 0
    1 -> 1
    _ -> 2
```

and indeed, `test 0 == 0`, `test 1 == 1`, and `test 77 == 2`.

The following function is *almost* as straightforward:

```
import Data.Ratio

test2 :: Rational -> Int
test2 = case x of
    0 -> 0
    1 % 2 -> 1
    _ -> 2
```

Loading this code in GHCi gives an error `Parse error in pattern: 1 % 2`.

What gives?  Why can't I pattern-match on rational numbers?  I can solve the real-world problem this example came from with guards, but I'm curious why pattern-matching doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can in general not pattern match on functions. That would require computing the inverse, which usually doesn't even exist. You can only match on *constructors* like [`Just`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:Just) or [`:+`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Complex.html#v:-58--43-): these are recognisable from ordinary functions / infix operators by starting with an uppercase character or a colon.

You *can* pattern match on rationals.

```
import GHC.Real (:%)

test2 :: Rational -> Int
test2 = case x of
    0 -> 0
    1 :% 2 -> 1
    _ -> 2
```

The reason, I suppose, why it's not really recommended to use `:%` (and it's hence only exported from an internal module, not from `Data.Ratio`) is that `Ratio` values are always supposed to be minimal, but `:%` as a plain constructor doesn't ensure this:

```
Prelude Data.Ratio GHC.Real> 4%2
2 % 1
Prelude Data.Ratio GHC.Real> 4:%2
4 % 2
```

In particular, if you'd then actually pattern-match on such an unnormalised fraction, you couldn't be sure to succeed.

In cases like `1%2`, you can circumvent the problem by pattern matching on a decimal fraction (finite decimal fractions are unique):

```
test2 :: Rational -> Int
test2 = case x of
    0   -> 0
    0.5 -> 1
    _   -> 2
```

Of course, this is perhaps not that nice. In modern Haskell, one could theoretically re-define `:%` as a smart pattern synonym:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms, ViewPatterns #-}
import Data.Ratio

numDenum :: Integral a => Ratio a -> (a,a)
numDenum x = (numerator x, denominator x)

pattern (:%) :: () => Integral a => a -> a -> Ratio a
pattern a:%b <- (numDenum -> (a,b))
 where a:%b = a%b
```

which could then be used as in your original example.

... but frankly, it's probably better to just use `numerator` and `denominator`as they are.

Comment: This is neat as heck, and I'll probably accept it.  But it doesn't quite answer the question of why I can't pattern-match on (%).  I'm not particularly familiar with the internals of pattern-matching, so it may be that there's a simple answer I'm not seeing.

Comment: Right, I added that to the top.

Comment: Oh, I see.  I guess I didn't realize that `(%)` wasn't actually a constructor, but you can just look at its `:info` and it's clearly not one.    The finite-decimal-fractions approach is a clever use of the default `Fractional a` type for decimals, which I'd forgotten about.

I'm not sure I quite understand the smart pattern synonym answer - I use dinosaur Haskell - but it looks like I've got some reading to do.  Thanks a bunch for the amazing answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use guards to do a very similar thing.  You can use arbitrary Bool expressions, so you have the `(%)` and every other pure function available.

```
test3 :: Rational -> Int
test3 x | x == 0 = 0
        | x == 1 % 2 = 1
        | otherwise = 2
```

They work in a case statement too.

```
test3a :: Rational -> Int
test3a y = case y of
    x | x == 0 -> 0
      | x == 1 % 2 -> 1
      | otherwise -> 2
```